# Cannot load images in GTK3. Error loading theme icon 'image-missing'

Tags: eclipse, gtk, fedora, gtk3

I have recently update Fedora 20 to Fedora 21 and after the update I've been having problems loading images in GTK3.

I have tried sample code as follows:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *image;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 1024, 768);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Image");
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 2);

    image = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/mbucko/image.jpg");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

When the function gtk_image_new_from_file is called I get the following print out:

```
(runtime:23246): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find the icon 'image-missing-ltr'. The 'hicolor' theme
was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
    http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases

(runtime:23246): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'image-missing' for stock: Icon 'image-missing' not present in theme

(runtime:23246): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'image-missing' for stock: Icon 'image-missing' not present in theme

(runtime:23246): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Then a window is displayed without the image.

I have hicolor-icon-theme-0.14-1 and gnome-icon-theme-devel-3.12 installed.

Gtk is 3.14.8.

Also have tried jpg, tiff and png files.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

EDIT:
Just found out that when I run the application from bash it works. I get this problem only when run from the Eclipse.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure the filename that you explicitly named is there, correct? Uppercase and lowercase is correct? Is there an `image-missing-ltr` in your icon theme's files? (I can't help much more, since I don't know about Fedora upgrades, sorry.)

Comment: You are loading image whose name is image.jpg but it's showing error for image-missing-ltr. Am I missing something here ? can you please specify the name properly.